# ¿Por qué "quedarse roque" significa dormirse?

Tags: expresiones, modismos

Con frecuencia decimos:

> Juan se ha quedado roque

Para decir que esa persona se ha quedado dormida, con cierta connotación de "muy dormido". La RAE lo contempla en su segunda acepción de la palabra:

> **[roque](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Whh3Pql%7CWhhVapo)**
>
> 1. adj. coloq. Dormido o vencido por el sueño. Estar, quedarse roque.

Sin embargo, me surge la duda: ¿alguien sabe por qué esta palabra? ¿Tiene que ver con que cuando alguien se queda dormido está como una roca, parada?

Comment: Leo por [aquí](http://www.santopedia.com/santos/san-roque) que el día de San Roque (o en honor de San Roque, no me queda claro) en algunos lugares de España los hombres despiertan a las mujeres que se han quedado en la cama hasta muy tarde. Tal vez por aquí venga el origen de la expresión.

Comment: "Roque" se puede user como adjetivo coloquial per se; es decir, que su único significado es "dormido" pero en un tono coloquial, como por ejemplo, "**quedarse frito o sobao**". Pero en este caso, no creo que venga de ningún significado específico, ya que roque, en este caso como nombre, significa también "**torre de ajedrez**" y "**carro de dos ruedas**".

Comment: Podría derivar, simplemente, de *roncando* como sinónimo de *durmiendo*. Sustituir una palabra con otra fonéticamente similar no es raro en expresiones coloquiales (por ejemplo, podemos decir *lo tengo clarinete* en lugar de *lo tengo claro*).

Answer (score 3):

Una posibilidad es que la expresión derive de San Roque, un santo popular que despierta bastante devoción en España y, por lo tanto, genera tradiciones.

Según [Santopedia](http://www.santopedia.com/santos/san-roque):

> ... en algunas zonas de Lleida, tenían a San Roque por patrón contra la gandulería. Hace muchos años, en el pueblo de Prat de Compte y en otras villas vecinas, los hombres tenían el derecho de poder levantar de la cama a aquellas mujeres que no eran bastante madrugadoras a juicio del vecindado masculino.

Tal vez por aquí venga el origen de la expresión. Yo me imagino que al paso del tiempo pudieron generarse dichos como "*hacer la del día de San Roque*" o similares, que luego se deformaron y confundieron hasta asimilar "roque" a la pereza y al sueño.

Pero es solo una suposición. Lamentablemente no pude encontrar más referencias que den más peso a esta respuesta, así que la dejo como posibilidad.

Comment: Es una suposición muy interesante. Lo curioso es que en catalán no existe la expresión "quedarse roque" y en Lleida es esa la lengua que se utiliza.