# ¿Por qué "tener frito" a alguien quiere decir que esa persona está cansada, tirando a harta?

Tags: modismos, expresiones, españa, coloquialismos

*Frito* es un adjetivo que se usa en distintos contextos. Por ejemplo, decimos que alguien *se ha quedado frito* si se ha quedado dormido profundamente (igual que [*quedarse roque*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16253/1674)).

La expresión que me pica la curiosidad hoy es la de "**tener frito**":

> -Mamá, ¿me compras un ordenador?
>
> -Niño, ya te he dicho que no. Me tienes frita ya de tanto pedir

Es decir, se usa *tener frito* para indicar que se está cansado, tirando a harto de una situación.

He buscado pero no he podido encontrar una explicación al respecto. ¿Alguien la sabe? Además, ¿se usa en algún lugar más que en España?

Comment: No sé la respuesta, pero "frito" es un adjetivo. Observa como concuerda con el nombre: "Me tienes frita ya con tanto pedir", "Se quedaron fritos"

Comment: @Toulousain tienes toda la razón. Tontamente pensé "modifica al verbo, así es que será adverbio". Gracias, ¡ya lo corregí!

Comment: *frito* se usa (o al menos se usaba, no sé de ahora) mucho en la Argentina.  Mafalda lo dice con frecuencia.

Comment: En Chile se usa bastante, pero significa otra cosa. Es más o menos haber llegado a un punto crítico en el que las consecuencias negativas se vuelven inminentes."Llegó la policía, estamos fritos".

Comment: @Rodrigo buen apunte, que veo que [el DRAE recoge](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IVbk9fv). Esto me hizo darme cuenta de que mi duda iba sobre _tener frito_ y no _estar frito_. Corregido, disculpad mi [empanada](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16532/1674) : )

Comment: En latinoamerica lo utilizamos en un contexto similar cuando la situación es irremediable o no hay ninguna solición a la vista, decimos "estoy frita". "¡Este gobierno nos tiene fritos!" "Mañana es el examen y no he podido estudiar, ¡estoy frita!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo creo que el origen de la expresión es el mismo que el de "estar quemado de algo".

Me explico: Cuando dejas algo mucho tiempo en aceite se fríe. Si lo dejas aún más, se quema. Así que en sentido figurado cuando estás muy cansado de una persona o de su actitud, en sentido figurado, la has aguantado tanto tiempo que "te fríe". Si es una situación, "te quema".

Yo soy española pero creo que al menos en México también se usa.

Comment: Pues me parece una explicación muy plausible. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Solo añadir a esta respuesta que el caso más antiguo que he encontrado es de 1849: "Sus prontos, sus prontos, que me tienen frita, dijo María fatigada".