# ¿Por qué “quedarse sopa” significa dormirse?

Tags: etimología, modismos

Preguntaba hace tiempo Fedorqui [por qué “quedarse roque” significa dormirse.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16253/5481)

[Quedarse sopa](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=quedarse%20sopa) es otra locución coloquial con el mismo significado, "quedarse dormido". Desafortunadamente la respuesta a la pregunta de "quedarse roque" no arroja mucha luz en este caso. Además, existen las locuciones ["hecho una sopa" o "como una sopa"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YNaQdnN) que significan "muy mojado".

No me soprendería entonces si "quedarse sopa" guardase más relación con "mojarse, quedarse mojado, clarse, etc."

¿Por qué “quedarse sopa” significa dormirse?

Comment: En [Estar/quedarse sopa/frito](http://www.blasita.com/estar-quedarse-sopa-frito/) citan _«Por otra parte quien se queda sopa se diluye, se convierte en líquido, pierde el conocimiento …; se duerme»_. Pero ni al autor del blog ni a mí nos convence demasiado. También mencionan que parece algo típico de España solamente, ¿alguien de Hispanoamérica puede confirmarlo?

Comment: *Quedarse frito* y *quedarse mosca* se usan en Argentina. *Quedarse sopa* nunca que yo haya escuchado.

Comment: En Argentina no se usa quedarse sopa, pero creo que se puede usar tranquilamente en el sentido de la tranquilidad que es inherente.
¿sabes que se usa? Quedarse pancho(hot dog) jajajja

Comment: La etimologia de las palabras muchas veces son propias de las costumbres de un lugar. Por ejemplo Atorrante que significa vulgarmente una persona vaga, sin obligaciones, en situacion de calle, realmente tiene su origen en la palabra A Torrar!!! que significaba A dormir, y lo usaban en la ciudad de Buenos Aires, en Argentina, para simbolizar a aquellas personas que no tenian lugar fijo donde descansar y lo hacian en los caños de desagüe cuando no traian agua.

Comment: No sé si ayudará en algo, pero me consta que, en Egipto, a veces el sonido /*p*/ lo hacen /*b*/. Lo sé por un viaje familiar que hicimos a esa tierra. El guía, aunque hablaba bien español, a la hora de pronunciar el nombre de mi cuñado ***P**aco*, decía ***B**aco*.

Answer (score 7):

Es posible que tenga que ver con el verbo latino **sopio**:

> [**sōpiō**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sopio#Latin) (*present infinitive* sōpīre, *perfect active* sōpīvī, *supine* sōpītum); *fourth conjugation*
>
> 1. I deprive of feeling.
> 2. I lull to sleep, put to sleep.

Que en su segunda acepción significa "poner a dormir".

Esto lo vi de por casualidad aquí: [referencia a sopitos](http://ettimologiia.blogspot.com.es/2009/03/la-pesadilla.html)

> **Meli**: sabes de dónde viene "sopor", soporífero, etc?
>   **Almudena**: pues no, pero una vez nos dio por esa palabrita y era todo el tiempo "qué sopor!"
>
> ```
> Del lat. sopor, -ōris).
> 1. m. Adormecimiento, somnolencia.
> 2. m. Med. Modorra morbosa persistente.
> ```
>
> **Meli**: y ... mira, no sé yo lo de quedarse sopa
>   pero en latín *sopitos* significa dormidos

Answer (score 2):

Por mi experiencia, las expresiones de cuño reciente son difíciles de rastrear cuando se trata de buscar su origen. Simplemente se pueden hacer especulaciones y tratar de ver sus primeros usos en textos escritos.

En el caso de *quedarse sopa*, este es el primer caso que aparece en el CREA:

> *¡Joder, Ofelia, tía!, ¿no podrías gritar más bajo? Me estaba quedando sopa.*
>
> ORAL. *¿Pero esto qué es?*, 05/03/90, TVE 1

Esto indica que la expresión debe tener su origen hacia finales de la década de 1980, si en marzo de 1990 ya estaba asentada en el habla (la primera expresión escrita en el CREA es de 1994). De la misma década de 1980 (o puede que un poco anterior) es también la creación de la acepción del verbo *sobar* como *dormir*:

> *—Aún estás dormido —comentó Nano.
>
>   Antonio levantó la mano, con gesto impotente.
>
>   —Me he quedado frito en la piltra —dijo—. Pasad.
>
>   Cerró la puerta y les condujo al salón.
>
>   —Sentaos por ahí. Voy por las zapatillas.
>
>   —¿Puedes tú solo o necesitas ayuda? —le preguntó Blanca, riendo.
>
>   Antonio se volvió hacia el grupo.
>
>   —Vaya colocón, esta tarde —dijo—. Ciegos nos hemos puesto los dos. Eso te hace volar, te pone en órbita a la tercera calada. ¡Menudo ciego! Si no llamáis vosotros, aún estamos sobando.*
>
> José Luis Tomás García, "La otra orilla de la droga", 1984 (España).

He incluido las frases previas para dar contexto al texto y que quede claro que se refiere al uso de *sobar* como *dormir*.

La creacion de esta acepción de *sobar* (que no entró en el DLE hasta 2001) introdujo la posibilidad de expresiones como "quedarse sobado". Por otro lado, tenemos la palabra "sopor", que significa "adormecimiento, somnolencia", con una raíz similar: *sop-* contra *sob-*. A partir de aquí ya es pura especulación, pero es posible que ambas palabras *sobar* y *sopor* se fusionaran en la expresión *quedarse sopa*. Así, tendríamos:

```
Estoy entrando en un estado de sopor 
me estoy quedando sobado             +
--------------------------------------
Me estoy quedando sopado/sopa.
```

En un principio podría pensarse en la expresión "quedarse sopado", pero el verbo *sopar* ya existía como "hacer sopa" o "quedarse hecho una sopa", y por tanto "quedarse sopado" tendría otro significado diferente, y la expresión se creó contraída: *quedarse sopa*.